# Responsive Grid System How to resize to 960px

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid-system

I used [this](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/) grid system. But its almost got 1000px width, I want to resize that 960px but I don't know how to do it. I also tried to give body{width:960px; margin:auto;} but this time I lost to main idea of responsivity..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid system use percentage for responsiveness. You may try to enclose the grid in a .container and there you define the width:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="span_12_of_12">
   ...
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
   width: 960px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: still same with it, but when I give em (max-width=60em;) value it'll fix! interesting. 960px = 60em i think.

Comment: sorry.good to know that you were able to find the solution..heheh.